# Redux thunk actions and sharing state

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-promise-middleware

I would like my application to be aware of when async actions are fired and when they complete. The reason for this is that I would like an overall `loading` state for my applications which sets to `true` when all async actions have completed. An early implementation of this used a global counter for callbacks.

These actions could be in different files and be listened to by separate reducers, responsible for different branches of state.

I'm using `thunk-middleware` combined with `redux-promise-middleware` so one of my async actions might look like this:

```
export const requestSiteData = () => (dispatch, getState, api) => {
  const url = '/endpoint';

  return dispatch({
    type: 'STATE_BRANCH/REQUEST_SOME_DATA',
    payload: api.fetch(url)
  }).catch(() => {});
};
```

This would then dispatch `STATE_BRANCH/REQUEST_SOME_DATA_FULFILLED` or `STATE_BRANCH/REQUEST_SOME_DATA_REJECTED` when complete.

Because of the promise middleware I'm finding it hard to intercept the call and count/determine how many ajax requests have been made and how many have completed because the actions are pre-determined and I can't dispatch another action from my reducers.

I can update state there obviously but the async actions may be split across several parts of the state tree so I don't have an overall place to manage the requests.

Does anyone have any ideas how I might go about solving this type of problem. Shout if the description/use case isn't clear.

Comment: Could you use a ```redux middleware``` for this ? http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html

Comment: He is already using redux middleware for this. redux-thunk and redux-promise are both pieces of middleware.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Redux middleware based around `redux-promise` that will help you keep track of pending actions:

[redux-pending](https://github.com/adriancooney/redux-pending)

Comment: This looks promising and similar to my existing setup. I'm happy to track the actions and resolutions myself but was wondering more whether there is a sensible way to push a list of pending actions into shared state. I'll have a play.

Answer (score -2):

A thunk is a chain of function that executes one by one so in your case your  code for async call should be

```
export function asyncAction() {
    return function(dispatch){
        fetchCall().then((data)=>data.json())
           .then((data)=>disptach(handleAsyncDataAction(data))
    }
```

and fetchCall() function should be write as.

```
function fetchCall(){
     return fetch('your_url');
}
```

and your handleAsyncData(data) action will return the result to the reducers so at the end for one fetch call you have to write 3 methods.

**1.** function you will call from Component

```
export function asyncAction(){..}
```

**2.** function who will written promise to this function

```
function fetchCall(){...}
```

**3.** and last function which will return handle return data and send it to reducer.

```
function handleAsyncData(data){....}
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm asking dude,  thanks for trying though